# Exporting PYQT5 application with sql database to .exe

Tags: mysql, pyqt5, exe

i've created a library management system with sql database

[image: Screenshot to project structure tree with sql file]

now i want to create a fully packed .exe file of this project with database so that no need of installing mysql server and heidie sql on client machine only need to install onee exe file and we are good to go.

Comment: You want to combine the MySQL DBMS into your application's exe file?

Comment: Ya, or any way to combine my database and pyqt5 application to one exe file only

Comment: No way that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

You may pack the main file with `pyinstaller`, then pack all the file, including the .exe generated with pyinstaller, with innoSetup.